# How can I get rid of the following warning: Problem while setting context on example startundefined local variable or method `selenium_driver' 

Tags: ruby, selenium, rubygems, rspec, specifications

Still making my first steps in Ruby (while dealing with some written code). I am getting the following warning each time I run `spec` (listed as is):

```
Problem while setting context on example startundefined local variable or method `selenium_driver' for #<Spec::Example::ExampleGroup::Subclass_1::Subclass_1:0x7f2d2cd840e0>
```

(**Edit**: Split into two lines, it says)

```
Problem while setting context on example start
undefined local variable or method `selenium_driver' for #<Spec::Example::ExampleGroup::Subclass_1::Subclass_1:0x7f2d2cd840e0>
```

While `grep`-ing through Ruby code - could find the following:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@frontend/gems/selenium-client-1.2.18/lib/selenium/rspec/spec_helper.rb:      STDERR.puts "Problem while setting context on example start" + e
```

So here is the excerpt from the source code of `spec_helper.rb`:

```
  config.append_before(:each) do
    begin
      if selenium_driver && selenium_driver.session_started?
        selenium_driver.set_context "Starting example '#{self.description}'"
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      STDERR.puts "Problem while setting context on example start" + e
    end
  end
```

Kindly advise how can I solve the (potential) problem.

**Update:** This `grep` might be helpful as well:

```
user@vm-ubuntu:~/dev/branch/tests$
grep selenium_driver *
my_module.rb:   @selenium_driver = driver
my_module.rb:   ['TERM', 'INT'].each {|s| Signal.trap(s) { @selenium_driver.stop && Process.exit(1) } }
my_module.rb:   return @selenium_driver
```

**Update N2:**

My `Gemfile`:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"            # Default source

gem "hpricot", "~>0.8.4"
gem "json", "~>1.5.1"
gem "rspec", "~>1.3.2"
gem "selenium-client", "~>1.2.18"
```

My `selenium_helper.rb` file:

```
require 'selenium/client'
require "selenium/rspec/spec_helper"
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `selenium-client` gem expects that you name your driver object `'selenium_driver'` **and** make it visible from the *spec*.

For example if you initialize selenium like this:

```
before(:all) do
  @driver = create_driver($hub_url, $hub_port, $browser) 
  @driver.start_new_browser_session
end
```

You need to change it to look like this:

```
attr_reader :selenium_driver

before(:all) do
  @selenium_driver = create_driver($hub_url, $hub_port, $browser) 
  @selenium_driver.start_new_browser_session
end
```

Basically it's same code just different variable name. The selenium-client uses that convention to apply context information to the tests.

Comment: Perfectly solves the problem! Is there a way I could know about that naming convention from error messages or by applying any other kind of magic? :)

Comment: Ok. I think I've got the message. Will try to propose an official bugfix.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying it can't find the variable `selenium_driver`.

```
Problem while setting context on example startundefined local variable or method `selenium_driver' for #<Spec::Example::ExampleGroup::Subclass_1::Subclass_1:0x7f2d2cd840e0>
```

is made up of the string `"Problem while setting context on example start"` plus the exception error message (what's produced by `e`) of

```
"undefined local variable or method `selenium_driver' for #<Spec::Example::ExampleGroup::Subclass_1::Subclass_1:0x7f2d2cd840e0>"`.
```

Comment: Please see the update - does it help to discover the reason for a problem (and yet to get rid of the warning)?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
gem "selenium-client"
```

to your **Gemfile** (don't forget to run `$ bundle install`)

And add following to **spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require "selenium/client"
require "selenium/rspec/spec_helper"
```

Comment: Kindly see my **Update N2**. Any tips/comments, please?

Comment: Are you sure RSpec requires your selenium_helper.rb? Why don't just add this to spec_helper.rb?

Comment: Those are good questions, however I am kinda new to all Ruby stuff and might do the things not in the best way. All I can say is that the existing code of (say) `my_test.rb` requires `selenium_helper.rb`. Is it the same like requiring `spec_helper.rb`? Also, the test works *fine*, but the warning is annoying indeed (_and_ might appoint to some problem). I can change the code and will do it, however, lots of code had been written so that the changes will come one by one.